# JSP problem in returning value from JavaScript and access in table

Tags: javascript, jsp

In javascript I am using the following function mdcal() and I want to use the values from the arrays mname,mresult in the table. I am unable to access the variables in table. Please help me to return the values from the function and use in table. If there is any other way please let me know. A sample of the code is shown below:

```
  function mdcal(){
     const mname = ["Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021"];
     const mresult = ["9.886", "10.011", "22.012"];
      }
```

Table in JSP:

```
 <table>        
  <tr>
            <c:forEach items="${mname}" var="mnm">
                       <th>${mnm}</th>          
                </c:forEach>
  </tr> 
  <tr>
                <c:forEach items="${mresult}" var="mres">
                    <td>${mres}</td>                    
                    </c:forEach>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your JSTL syntax is correct. But, EL accesses scoped variables. You don't show us where you put mname and mresult into scope.  JSP is compiled on the server. JavaScript is evaluated at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

Constants declared inside of the `mcal` function are out of the visibility scope.
I suppose you should declare constants outside of the `mcal` function, and define values returned from two separate functions:

```
  function names(){
    return ["Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021"];
  };

  function results(){
    return ["9.886", "10.011", "22.012"];
  };

  const mname = names();
  const mresult = results();
```

Or define variables instead of  values of the each variable at the `mcal` function, but declaration should be.

```
  var mname = [];
  var mresult = [];


  function mcal(){
    mname = ["Jan 2021", "Feb 2021", "Mar 2021"];
    mresult = ["9.886", "10.011", "22.012"];
  }
```